# Sporadic audio playback issue on Voxeo Prophecy (audio playback conflict)

Tags: audio, ccxml, voxeo

Prophecy version: 14.5.2

I am using the following CCXML line to playback audio files over a phone call:

```
<dialogstart src="'NoResponse.wav'" type="'audio/wav'"/>
```

This works the majority of the time. However sometime a few threads will begin having errors during the playback of an audio file, this doesn't seem to be tied to any specific audio file. In the logs I get a SIP event error with the following details (only showing relavent bits from log):

> CTStream/Failed to read from VIO accessor.
>   CTStream/Transcoder:failed to read from backbone.
>   Reading from playback stream has failed.
>   name="error.dialog.notstarted"  reason="audio playback conflict"

Any information the leads to the resolution of this issue would be greatly appreciated. I have not found any information on this in the Prophecy documents.